# Is the primary key property also marked as modified when use DbSet<T>.Update() method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

The definition of DbSet.Update() is :

**"Begins tracking the given entity.... ...All properties of the entity will be marked as modified."**

does it include the primary key property? If the primary key property also marked as modified, why the primary key in not in generated SQL's `Set [primarykey] = XXX`?(where XXX should be the same primary key value as the one in database)

Comment: Are you using .NET Core or not?

Comment: @GabrielLuci  .Net Core

Comment: Ok. I only ask because the `entity-framework` tag is only for non-Core, so I'll remove it. I believe it doesn't make a difference in this case, but there are some major differences in some cases.

Comment: The question is irrelevant because both EF and EFCore do not update Primary Keys.

Comment: @ErikPhilips  so why the definition of `DbSet.Update` says: "All properties of the entity will be marked as modified."? it should says explicitly sth like "except primary key properties "?

Comment: @secondimage You can add feedback to the [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.update) and request that they change the wording.

Comment: @secondimage it's still irrelevant.  If the key is not marked, it won't be updated.  If the key for some reason could be marked, it still **will not be** updated.

Comment: @ErikPhilips   could you have a look at this post?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57471685/differences-in-marking-modified-properties-between-dbset-attach-and-dbset-upda      even non-key is unmodified, it still get updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the answer is no, but you can check this for yourself.

[`DbSet.Update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.update?view=efcore-2.1) returns "The [`EntityEntry`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.entityentry?view=efcore-2.1) for the entity", which you can use to see which properties it has marked as modified. For example:

```
var entity = dbContext.MyTable.Update(myRecord);
foreach (var modifiedProperty in entity.Properties.Where(p => p.IsModified)) {
    Console.Write($"The {modifiedProperty.Metadata.Name} property is marked as modified");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just tried that, yes, the primary key is not considered as "modified". but if I use `DbSet.Attach` and change a property(non-key properties, the `entity.State` is unchanged and no properties are modified, but still EF generated an Update SQL to `set [Modifiedproperty] = XXX`, I'm confused, if the entity state is unchanged and EF think there is no property modifications, then EF shouldn't generate an Update SQL?

Comment: That, I don't know. I do have a .NET Core project I can test with tomorrow.