# Differences in marking modified properties between DbSet.Attach() and DbSet.Update()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

let's say we have a Person class(with properties of Id and Age), let's say we need to change the Age of a person whose id is 1 from 29 to 30, and I use `DbSet.Update()` and `DbSet.Attach()` respectively:

```
Person p = new Person(){ Id = 1 }  
var entity = context.Persons.Update(p);
p.Age = 30;

Console.WriteLine("entity state:" + entity.State);
foreach (var modifiedProperty in entity.Properties.Where(p => p.IsModified))
{
   Console.Write($"The {modifiedProperty.Metadata.Name} property is marked as modified,");
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

output:

> entity state:Modified.
>
> The Age property is marked as modified,The Name property is marked as modified*

which is expected result, but if I use `Attach()` as

```
Person p = new Person(){ Id = 1 }  
var entity = context.Persons.Attach(p);
p.Age = 30;

Console.WriteLine("entity state:" + entity.State);
foreach (var modifiedProperty in entity.Properties.Where(p => p.IsModified))
{
   Console.Write($"The {modifiedProperty.Metadata.Name} property is marked as modified,");
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

output:

> entity state:Unchanged.

and nothing after, since no properties has been identified as modified, but I changed the Age property the same way as in Update() method, why `Attach()` cannot identify modified properties? if `Attach()` cannot identify modified properties, how come it still generate the correct update sql statement to database?

Answer (score 0):

You are very much confusing *what is in sql server* with *what is in the context cache*.  The DbContext caches entities and tracks them so it knows what to do when `SaveChanges()` is called.  If the entity **does not exist** in the cache, it is **up to the developer to help entity-framework determine the correct logic**.

[DbSet.Update(TEntity) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.update?view=efcore-2.1)

> Begins tracking the given entity in the Modified state such that it will be updated in the database when SaveChanges() is called.

[DbSet.Attach(TEntity) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.attach?view=efcore-2.1)

> Begins tracking the given entity in the Unchanged state such that no operation will be performed when SaveChanges() is called.

Onto your point:

> but I changed the Age property the same way as in Update() method

Yes you did, but that does not change how you attached it.  Order of events is very important.  In the following example, we change Age to 31 **before** we attach the entity to the Entity Framework Context.  It does not know you changed it was not tracking it at the time the change occurred (record will NOT change to 31):

```
using (var context = new EntityContext())
{
    p.Age = 31;
    context.Persons.Attach(p);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

> if Attach() cannot identify modified properties, how come it still generate the correct update sql statement to database

If we change the order of events to Attach the entity **before** we change a values, then Entity Framework can detect the change an save it to the DB (record will CHANGE to 32):

```
using (var context = new EntityContext())
{
    context.Persons.Attach(p);
    p.Age = 32;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

All Working Examples:

[DotNetFiddle Core Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FNtbfL)

```
// Entity Framework Extensions
// Doc: https://entityframework-extensions.net/context-factory

// @nuget: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
// nuget: Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore
// @nuget: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
// @nuget: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var p = new Person();
        using (var context = new EntityContext())
        {
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            p.Age = 29;
            context.Persons.Add(p);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var context = new EntityContext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Created Person Age 29");
            FiddleHelper.WriteTable("Student", context.Persons.ToList());
        }

        using (var context = new EntityContext())
        {
            p.Age = 30;
            context.Persons.Update(p);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var context = new EntityContext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Update Person Age 30");
            FiddleHelper.WriteTable("Student", context.Persons.ToList());
        }

        using (var context = new EntityContext())
        {
            p.Age = 31;
            context.Persons.Attach(p);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var context = new EntityContext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Change Person to 31, THEN Attach");
            FiddleHelper.WriteTable("Student", context.Persons.ToList());
        }

        using (var context = new EntityContext())
        {
            context.Persons.Attach(p);
            p.Age = 32;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var context = new EntityContext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Attach THEN Change Person to 32");
            FiddleHelper.WriteTable("Student", context.Persons.ToList());
        }

    }

    public class EntityContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var connectionString = FiddleHelper.GetConnectionStringSqlServer();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Philps  I did the same thing as you did. My question is,  I change Age property after I attached the object, why  Dbcontext still think the entity state is unchanged and none of properties is in modified status?

Comment: by the way, I'm very confused with the definition of DbSet.Attach, it says "no operation will be performed when SaveChanges() is called", but if you change sth after the attach, update operation will be performed(in my case, Age is updated)?